# What kind of spider is this from Nova Scotia, Canada?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

[image]

What kind of spider is this? It was found in Nova Scotia, Canada and is about the size of a quarter.

Answer (score 3):

That is an *[Araneus diadematus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araneus_diadematus)*, a kind of garden [orb-web spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orb-weaver_spider).

[image]

Orb-weaving spiders are quite common, and can be found nearly anywhere in the world, excluding Greenland. The following is a distribution map for the species *A. diadematus*, of which, as you can see, is mostly contained to North America & Canada.

[image]
*Dark gray: present; Light gray: no record. ([source](http://bugguide.net/node/view/3376/data))*